# zend multiple table interface

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

I have to add secondary table inside on DPTable interface. How is it possible?

for example on the following code :

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_PlanList extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

protected $_name = 'hosted_plans';

public function list_plan()
{
    $row = $this->fetchAll();
    if (!$row) 
    {
        throw new Exception("Could not find row $id");
    }
    return $row->toArray();
}
public function list_plan_features()
{

        $table = new HostedPlanContentMapping();

        $select = $table->select();
        $select->from($table);
        $row = $table->fetchAll($select);


    if(!$row)
    {
        throw new Exception("Could not find result");
    }
    return $row->toArray();


}
}
```

IN above code list_plan function using hosted_plans table. I have to add another function on this same class to fetch details from HostedPlanContentMapping. which I tried to do with list_plan_features(). and calling on controller like below:

```
$featurelist = new Application_Model_DbTable_PlanList();
$this->view->listfeature = $featurelist->list_plan_features();
```

But not getting result.

Can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative, you can always call the DB adapter directly from the Table object, if you wish. Something like the following:

```
    $select = $this->getAdapter()->select();
    $select->from($tableName);
    $row = $this->getAdapter()->fetchAll($select);
```

Hope that helps,